# Regular expression length

Tags: javascript, regex

What do you think about using looooooong regular expressions? Does this affect performance?

This is one of my regular expressions: (blockquote messed it up, so I edited it)

`([(]((((-?((([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))|(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))[*/]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|(-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|([(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)][+/*-]([(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)]|(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+/*-]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|[(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)]))|(-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+/*-]((([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))|[(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)])))([+/*-](((-?((([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))|(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))[*/]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|(-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|([(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)][+/*-]([(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)]|(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+/*-]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|[(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)]))|(-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+/*-]((([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))|[(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)])))|(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))|[(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)]))*)|(((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))|[(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)])([+/*-]((-?((([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))|(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))[*/]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|(-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|([(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)][+/*-]([(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)]|(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+/*-]((([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))|[(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)]))|(-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+/*-]((([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))|[(]((-?(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))[+-](([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)])))|(-?(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))[+-](([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))))[)]))))+))[)])`

Can i use RegExp this length or is it bad practise?

EDIT
I'm constructing complex number calculator. This regex is made from shorter ones. This is how i am doing it:

```
    var regularExpression = new (function() 
{
    this.re = "(([0-9]+)|([(]-[0-9]+[)]))",
    this.im = "(([0-9]*i)|([(]-[0-9]*i[)]))",
    this.complexNumber = "[(]((-?"+ this.re + "[+-]" + this.im + ")|(-?" + this.im + "[+-]" + this.re +"))[)]",
    this.expression = "("+
                                                "(-?("+this.re+"|"+this.im+")[*/]("+this.im+"|"+this.re+"))|"+
                                                "(-?"+this.re+"[+-]"+this.im+"[+-]("+this.im+"|"+this.re+"))|"+
                                                "("+this.complexNumber+"[+/*-]("+this.complexNumber+"|"+this.im+"|"+this.re+"))|"+
                                                "(-?"+this.im+"[+/*-](" + this.im+"|"+this.complexNumber+"))|"+
                                                "(-?"+this.re+"[+/*-](" + this.re+"|"+this.complexNumber+"))"+
                                        ")",
    this.simpleExpression = "([(]("+
                                                        "("+this.expression+"([+/*-]("+this.expression+"|"+this.im+"|"+this.re+"|"+this.complexNumber+"))*)|"+
                                                        "(("+this.im+"|"+this.re+"|"+this.complexNumber+")([+/*-]"+this.expression+")+)"+
                                                    ")[)])"
})();
```

So my regularExpression.simpleExpression is even longer, because is uses expression few times. Thats why I'm asking and worried.

simpleExpression is looking for strings like: (12321-12231i+1233123*(12i-231)+12323-i)

Comment: First thing I want to say is : This is bad for code readability and maintenance or debugging. In a performance point of view, I don't know

Comment: This expression is divided into parts end explained in comments. I construct it from strings, so readability is not bad at all.

Comment: I see some potential repetition in your regex.  Could you let us know what this really long regex is supposed to be doing?

Comment: It is repeating a lot. Im constructing complex calculator, and this expression is made from shorter expressions. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Well I guess this is dependent of what you are doing. If you have a realy long search therm the performance is not nessesarely longer than a short one, since the engine can mostly search it with linear complexity. The most performance is lost with conditional statements like `123(45|67)890` or lookaheads and lookbacks.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work on https://regex101.com/. Maybe you could make it look a little bettter there and edit it here?

Comment: It is working on regex101.com - i tested it there. Just make sure you choose javascript.

Comment: You can use `\(` instead of `[(]`, same goes for closing parentheses

Comment: I dont know why, but when I paste my regex here, and copy it into regex101.com it is not working. But it works when i copy it from my program...

Comment: What is a regexp like this? Are you trying to validate it?

Comment: You need such a regexp for looking strings like `(12321-12231i+1233123*(12i-231)+12323-i)`?… Sounds weird, no? ;-) (I mean: a shorter one should make the job) Could you give a real example in the real life? It's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are very fast, when they are written in a good manner (definitely much faster than e.g. the code based on conditionals).

However, the question you should ask yourself is whether the code is maintainable and readable - someone may have to rewrite this part of the code in the future and even you might not understand it at first glance after some time.

First point from here might answer your question: https://hackernoon.com/few-simple-rules-for-good-coding-my-15-years-experience-96cb29d4acd9

Comment: Thanks for answer. Code is easy to maintain, so i stick with it. Again - thanks!